# Checking if any textboxes contain text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a HTML structure like this:

```
<div class="input_div_0">
    <input type="text" class="textbox input">
</div>
<div class="input_div_1">
    <input type="text" class="textbox input">
</div>
<div class="input_div_2">
    <input type="text" class="textbox input">
</div>
```

I want to write an expression that will return true if any of the `input`s contain text

**EDIT**

Based on Dimitar's answer I've come up with this:

```
function checkInputs()
{
    $('input.textbox').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() !== "") {
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}

if (!checkInputs()) {
        //Display message
    }
```

However the false is returned every time.

Answer (score 7):

Try utilizing `Array.prototype.some`

```js
var res = Array.prototype.some.call(document.querySelectorAll("input")
          , function(el, i) {
              return el.value.length > 0
          });

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_div_0">
  <input type="text" class="textbox input">
</div>
<div class="input_div_1">
  <input type="text" class="textbox input">
</div>
<div class="input_div_2">
  <input type="text" class="textbox input" value="0">
</div>
```

Comment: Value.length not just value

Comment: You could also call the `call` method on `some` function instead of using `slice`. `Array.prototype.some.call(document.querySelectorAll("input"), fn)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="text"]').each(function() {
    console.log(!!$(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkInput(){
   var result = false;
   $('input.textbox').each(function() {
      if($(this).val() !== ""){
         result = true;
      };
   });
   return result;
};
```

Comment: The "return true" part will not end the function; it just returns true for the loop. Thus you will always end up going to the "return false" portion. Try using a variable to store the information like I did in my example.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Working example https://jsfiddle.net/d313m9vL/

```
$(function(){
    function isEmpty(){
        var inputs = $("input[type=text]");
        if(inputs.val().length === 0)
            return true;
    }

    $("button")
    .on("click", function(){
        if(isEmpty) alert("error");
    });

});
```